# C# Send information over TCP

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, tcp

**I'm still learning C#, so don't yell at me for not doing anything right. Also, i know I should probably be using WPF, but in my current condition I need to use winForms.**

Client:

```
public void sendData(String dataIn)
{
    String IP = textBox1.Text;
    String Port = textBox2.Text;
    net.Send(dataIn, IP, Port);
}
```

Server:

```
public string listenForData()
{
    String dataOut = net.Listen();
    return dataOut;
}
```

How do I create a method that takes a string and sends it to a server application. I know it has something to do with TCP sockets. I've looked but I don't understand any tutorials or videos i've found.

> Thanks in advance, Noah.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The question has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try looking into the TCP Client Class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

You can get the stream from tcp client and use that to write your string to, by converting the string to a byte[] first.

```
// Setup TCP Client with valid values first. Make Client and stream private or public variables/properties.

TCPClient client = new TCPClient(IP, (int)Port); // Following validation on Port & IP
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

private void SendDataToServer(String dataIn) {
     Byte[] StringToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataIn);
     stream.Write(StringToSend, 0, StringToSend.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You simplified this well.

Comment: Also this is using a UTF8 Encryption? Not a problem just saw that and was wondering.

Comment: UTF8 is a type of text encoding. You can just as easily use ASCII or another type of encoding, so long as the server is able to decode from it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! This will help a lot.